# No route matches {:action=>"partner_update", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm new in rails so i tried to do this to add a role, making a form to update and if the user update succsessfully add the role. 
note: i'm using devise and rolify with cancancan

routes

```
 get 'users/becomepartner' => 'users#becomepartner' do
  collection do
    patch 'update_partner'
  end
end
```

and this is my users controller

```
def becomepartner
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update_partner
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_with_password(partner_params)
        self.add_role(:partner)
      # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
      bypass_sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'now you can create'
    else
      render :becomepartner
    end
  end

  private

  def partner_params
    # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :style, :current_password, :email)
  end
```

and this is my view becomepartner.html

```
<div>
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_partner" } ) do |f| %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :style %>
   <%= f.text_field :style %>
 </div>

     <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i>
      <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it is `update_partner` instead of `partner_update`, show your `rake routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form action you have mentioned action as `partner_update` but you don't have that action. Change it to `update_partner`.

You are using the `collection` route for another individual route, that is `get 'users/becomepartner'`. So this will generate the collection route with url like:

```
users/becomepartner/update_partner
```

You can confirm this by running `rake routes`.

But your forms action url will be different.

What you can do is create this collection route inside users resource route like:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
   patch 'update_partner'
  end
end
```

Then in form_for url option, use `update_partner_users_path`

If you don't want the users resources routes, then just define a single route like:

```
get 'users/becomepartner' => 'users#becomepartner'
patch 'user/update_partner' => 'users#update_partner'
```

I have not ran any of this code, so if there is any syntax error then post it in comment.

Comment: thank you, i haven't notice it LOL, but it still the same error.

Comment: You mean, still it is searching for the action `partner_update` ?

Comment: no, the problem is the same but the name of the action i've changed like you said, No route matches {:action=>"update_partner", :controller=>"users"}

Answer (score 0):

1. In `routes.rb`,change 
   `patch 'update_partner'` to `update 'update_partner'` and remove collection as you are not operating on a collection.you have added it in a `do block`,instead add a one liner route path.
2. in the **form**,`url` must be `update_partner` and NOT `partner_update` .

Comment: can you remove collection from the routes as it a single object...check my updated answer.